# Trouble adding a library android project to a UI android project

Tags: java, android, buildpath

I know this topic was asked a few times but I'm getting back and forward with the following issue:

I have two android projects on Eclipse:

- EngineProject
- UIProject

I'm trying to add EngineProject as a library to UI project but I get the following errors:

1. Defining the Engine project as "isLibrary" (in the "Android" section) and adding it as a library to the UIProject resulting "Error Type3 -> Cannot find MainActivity".
2. Removing the Engine project from the Library section on the UIProject resulting if a NoClassDefFoundException when referring it from the UIProject.

Both projects are compiling correctly since the EngineProject is in the Build-Path of the UIProject.

What can be the solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- I think the EngineProject as a library project can't hava
  MainActivity.
- Does EngineProject has MainActivity?

  If it is, remove
  the intent-filter about MainActivity in manifest.xml

Comment: Hi. 
No, EngineProject is a library project with no view included.